# How to get the realm information from an second activity?

Tags: java, android, realm

I got the schoolID from the main activity, which is base on realm from a json file. Using the school ID I am trying to get the students name.

My question is how to get the students name and how to list the students from the student adapter.  Thanks.

The following is the student activity:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {

        String schoolName = extras.getString("schoolName");


        RealmResults<School> schools = realm.where(School.class).findAll();

        //RealmResults<School> school =  realmStudent.where(School.class).equalTo("SchoolName", schoolName).findAll();
        // Log.d(tag, String.valueOf(school));
    }
}
```

The following is the school class:

```
@Required
private String SchoolID;
private String SchoolName;
private RealmList<Student> Students;
```

The following is the main activity:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){

    super.onResume();

    if(mAdapter == null) {
        List<School> schools = null;
        try {
            schools = loadSchools();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    RealmResults<School> schools = realm.where(School.class).findAll();
    final SchoolAdapter adapter = new SchoolAdapter(this, R.id.schools_list, schools, true);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.schools_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

         String schoolName  = adapter.getRealmResults().get(position).getSchoolName();

            startStudentList(schoolName);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    realm.close();
}

public void startStudentList(String schoolName){

    //String schoolName = school.getSchoolName();

    Intent schoolIntent = new Intent(this, StudentActivity.class);

    schoolIntent.putExtra("schoolName", schoolName);
   // Log.d(tag, String.valueOf(schoolName));

    startActivity(schoolIntent);


}

public List<School> loadSchools() throws IOException{

    loadJsonFromStream();

    return realm.allObjects(School.class);

}

private void loadJsonFromStream() throws IOException {

    InputStream stream = getAssets().open("school.json");

    realm.beginTransaction();
    try {
        realm.createAllFromJson(School.class, stream);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        realm.cancelTransaction();
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();


        }
    }

}
```

The following is the school adapter:

```
public class SchoolAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<School> implements ListAdapter {

private static class ViewHolder{
    TextView school;
}

public SchoolAdapter(Context context, int resId, RealmResults<School> realmResults, boolean automaticUpdate) {
    super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.school = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    School item = realmResults.get(position);
    viewHolder.school.setText(item.getSchoolName());
    return convertView;
}

public RealmResults<School> getRealmResults() {
    return realmResults;
}

}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the list of students. You already have the `School` in your `SchoolAdapter`. So calling `item.getStudents()` should give you the list of students. Then you can do whatever you want with them?

Comment: I would like to get a list view of students after I click any school.  Is there a way to do it in the same activity.  I could not retrieve the object from school object when I pass it to another activity even I can pass the value to the student activity.

Comment: @Spidey You pass the `SchoolID` to another activity and do a query to find the `School` object there. Then as Christian suggested, using `item.getStudents()` for your list view there.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use string array in XML file .