# How to set identifiers for my realm object?

Tags: java, android, realm

How to set identifiers for my realm object..I need to use it for query in my 2nd activity in my Android application.  Thanks.

School object:

```
public class School extends RealmObject {

@Required
private String SchoolID;
private String SchoolName;
private RealmList<Student> Students;


getters/setters

public RealmList<Student> getStudents() {
    return Students;
}

public void setStudents(RealmList<Student> students) {
    Students = students;
}
```

Student Object:

```
public class Student extends RealmObject{

@Required
private String StudentID;
private String StudentName;

getters/setters

}
```

Comment: Do you mean Primary Key by identifiers ?

Comment: I am not sure...I need to use it to retrieve data from my realm object.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329224/how-to-get-the-realm-information-from-an-second-activity?noredirect=1#comment56522810_34329224  It is also relate to https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/567

Comment: `@PrimaryKey private String SchoolID;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@PrimaryKey`: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#primary-keys

```
public class Student extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private String StudentID;
private String StudentName;

// getters/setters

}
```